# PHP setcookie has stopped working with no code change

Tags: php, cookies

I know this question gets asked a million times but this one is very different. This code has worked flawlessly for over 3 years but now has stopped working.

The cookie in question holds a members id for an 'auto login' when returning to the site. The cookie is set via a jQuery call to a function upon log in. Once they are logged in the function returns a value and the calling script redirects the member to their control panel:

```
        if (strlen(trim($_POST['keep_logged'])) != 0)   {

            if(setcookie('foacmemberinformation', $row['member_id'],  time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/'))    {
                error_log('in set cookie line 68');
                }
            else    {
                error_log('set cookie failed');
                }
            }
```

I just added the if else statement around the set cookie to verify that the set cookie function is returning true.

What seems to be causing it is when a member uses the 'log out' function on the site which is as simple as this:

```
session_start();

session_destroy();

setcookie('foacmemberinformation', '', time() - 3600);

header('Location: /Member-Login');
```

Now I personally have used this log out, then log back in and remember function hundreds if not thousands of times over the past three year and have never had an issue until now. It also is happening in all browsers.

I have verified that setcookie is returning true and there is no output before except another cookie (setcookie('foacmemberstate', $row['state'],  time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 14, '/');) which IS being set. I even commented that set cookie out and tried and still the 'problem' cookie is not setting.

I don't get what is happening after it worked for 3 years!

Comment: I am using Firefox for the main testing and checked both in the web developer tool bar and in the FF options and the cookies are not there ... weird beyond weird

Comment: I checked the timestamp on the code that handles this and it was last uploaded over a year ago.

There have been no breeches I know of and I am the only person with FTP access to the code. 

Lastly it's hosting on one of my dedicated boxes, had there been an attack I would have seen something (well I SHOULD have seen something)